# std type_traits conflict with Qt type_traits

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, type-traits

I have Qt 5.8 installed and i get this error.
I also have CONFIG  += c++14 in my pro file and i also tried with c++11.

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qtimer.h:106: error: ‘is_same’ is not a member of ‘QtPrivate’!QtPrivate::is_same<const
```

also

```
/usr/include/c++/5/type_traits:958: note:   ‘std::is_same’
     struct is_same;
```

Comment: This question could be improved by a bit of context and detail: 1) The error message seems to be cut off, provide the full message. 2) *When* do you get that error? Compiling one of your applications? Compiling Qt?

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57020

Comment: Are you sure about the version installed? [This commit](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/ed7f77071dcca996a8c8147fd66344090666e60c#diff-1d7b29380800db7c17a425e088a01847) should fix this IMO, and as far as I can see it should be in 5.8.0.

Comment: That `/usr/include/` *`x86_64-linux-gnu`* `/qt5/QtCore/qtimer.h` looks weird. Maybe you are mixing headers files from different versions of Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been doing some digging in the Qt git repository, based on the comment to the question by @DanielJour.

Looking to the history of file `qtimer.h` and correlating it to your error message (`qtimer.h:106: error: ‘is_same’ is not a member...`), I've found that [this commit](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/1a88b2f768e86474f8fc6facf60cd0dd46a555c8#diff-1d7b29380800db7c17a425e088a01847R112) moved the call to `is_same` from line 106 to 112 (and never came back), so you are including a `qtimer.h` from **before** that commit.

That commit is from 2016-01-15 and it is included from Qt 5.7 onwards.

So my guess is that you have installed several different versions of Qt and somehow your program is including old headers, not the ones from Qt 5.8.

An additional note that leads me to that conclusion is that your header file is in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/`, but the usual place where that is installed is in `/usr/include/qt` or `/usr/include/qt5`. Yours looks like a multilib or cross compiler path...